# Ionic splashscreen is broken after ProGuard/DexGuard

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor, dexguard

We're using [SplashScreen](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen) plugin on the Ionic App, which seems to work fine on usual debug and release builds.
But when we turn on the DexGuard/ProGuard for build steps and generate a protected APK file,
there the splash screen is not shown at all.

Instead, a black screen is shown with **white** strange borders and no spinner anymore.

Here are the screenshots before and after Dexguard:
[image: Before DexGuard]
[image: After DexGuard]

In dexguard rules I've added the following lines to avoid renaming the splash screen images

```
-keepresourcefiles res/**
```

But it didn't help.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out dexguard was somehow still touching the splash screen files or resource names.
As a quick fix adding this rule worked:

```
-keepresources */*
```

But we might need a better and more specific solution.